# remove toast and also destroy or force stop thread

Tags: android, thread-safety

hi i am working on custom toast , and i am able to do that, but after when i move to next activity the thread is running or active of back activity , so what should i do for removing that thread or stop this thread.

my code is given below :

```
public void customToast(int x, int y, String str) {
    if (Util.tipson == true) {
        toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, x, y);
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        toastView = li.inflate(R.layout.toastlayout, null);
        toast.setView(toastView);
        TextView text = (TextView) toastView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(str);
        // toast.show();

        fireLongToast();
    }

}

private void fireLongToast() {

    t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            int count = 0;
            try {
                while (true && count < 40) {
                    try {
                        toast.show();
                        sleep(100);
                        count++;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                    // do some logic that breaks out of the while loop
                }

                toast = null;
                toastView = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("LongToast", "", e);
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Need to stop your thread by yourself. Since java doesn't allow you to use stop() function.

Write class for your Thread as this

```
public class YourThread extends Thread {
        private volatile boolean stopped = false;

        public void run() {
            int count = 0;
            try {
                while (true && count < 40 && !stopped) {
                    try {
                        toast.show();
                        sleep(100);
                        count++;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                    // do some logic that breaks out of the while loop
                }

                toast = null;
                toastView = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("LongToast", "", e);
            }
        }

        public void stopThread() {
            stopped = true;
        }
    }
```

Now when your Activity which has the Thread Finishes stop Your thread

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
   if(isFinishing())
      yourThreadVariable.stopThread();
}
```

Comment: in this when we want to show more toast in one activity it might occur problems. have you tried this ? please give me sollution for that

Answer (score 0):

Does [finishing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) the activity have any effect?

Comment: thanx for reply, i am finish the activity but it does not works to stop the thred.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know for sure, but you can call the function `join` of `thread` in `onDestroy` of your activity.

Comment: told you that m not sure but i read it from some tutorial... anyways check this link... http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29

Comment: join() has nothing to do with this, use stop() instead. PS. join() makes current thread wait til the thread you called join() on finish

Answer (score 0):

To stop the thread you can just use `interrupt()`. But for better solution I would say not to use `Thread`. Just create a `Handler` with `Runnable` and manage your `Runnable` using `Handler`, that would be a nice way as `Android` has given Handler for managing one or more `Runnables`.

**Creating a Runnable**

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // put your code stuff here
        }
    };
```

**To start Runnable use**

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, your_time_in_millis);
```

**To stop Runnable use**

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest Lalit Poptani method too and implement this:

```
protected void onStop(){
   handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
   super.onStop();
}
```

The documentation for the method:

> onStop,Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user, because another activity has been resumed and is covering this one. This may happen either because a new activity is being started, an existing one is being brought in front of this one, or this one is being destroyed.
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html